# How to send data to laptop from android phone?

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to connect my phone directly to my laptop using sockets in java. My error message is Could not execute method for android:onclick. My router is a Netgear Nighthack AC1900 Model no c6900. below is code for android app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String message;
EditText messagetv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        messagetv = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        message = "no value";
    }

    public void connect(View view) {
        message = messagetv.getText().toString();
        try {
            Socket s2044 = new Socket("My ip address",2488);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s2044.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(message);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code for laptop:
'''

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "no data";
    try {
        ServerSocket socket2488 = new ServerSocket(2488);
        System.out.println(socket2488.getLocalSocketAddress());
        Socket s2044=socket2488.accept();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s2044.getInputStream());
        str =(String) dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println("from client  " + str);
        socket2488.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

}
'''
I am currently able to connect two laptops to each other when they are on the same network so I think it is an issue with my router or phone.
I also noticed on the  System.out.println(socket2488.getLocalSocketAddress()); gives the ip address value as 0.0.0.0

Comment: What is in the stacktrace?  Yes, the problem *could be* something to do with the way your networks are set up. The `0.0.0.0` is the wild card address.

Comment: I think this is what your looking for https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YWeKkaTiaGcuYarcpOspla0kjkhTG7dKgdsoNvYtv-0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To check your network, install a webserver on your laptop and try to connect from your phone using the standard browser. If that does not work, check the laptop's firewall, then the router settings. Sometimes WLAN and LAN are two different segments that need to be allowed to see each other (bridged mode).